# How to theme /comment/# page

Tags: 7, theming, comments

Currently `example.com/comment/#` shows the contents of the node that the comment is posted to. I want the page to only show the comment.

I'm assuming the page does not theme via .tpl.php. And if it isn't, do I put something like this in the template.php, and how do I override the current content of that page:

```
$comment = _comment_load($cid);
return theme('comment',$comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no conventional way of doing this as far as I'm aware but if you want to do this it can probably be achieved with some processing in your theme.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // DO SOMETHING WITH request_uri() or similar

  if (isset($SOME_VARIABLE)) {
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__comments";
  }
}
```

Then create a copy of your page template as page--comments.tpl.php and take out what you dont need.

This is nasty though and not the 'Drupal' way of doing things.